# How do i do user = request.user in views.py just because i have foreign key in my model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How do i update user field in views.py just because i have a view to edit and delete posts associated with the user. I also have a view that fetch products with user == request.user and show in the profile page. Almost my site is dependent on post creation.Please let me know how can I update that user foreign key while saving the form( ex:- product.user = request.user )

*My Models.py*

````
```class Product(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
       details = models.TextField(default="...") ....```
````

*My Forms.py*

````
```class AddUserPacksForm(forms.ModelForm):
       user = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="",
                                  queryset=User.objects.all(),
                                  widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
       title = forms.CharField(label='Title', widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       details = forms.CharField(label='Description', widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       image = forms.FileField(label='Thumbnail', widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       sp = forms.IntegerField(label='Selling Price', widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       dp = forms.IntegerField(label='Discounted Price', widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       buy_link = forms.CharField(
       label='Buy Link ( i.e Instagram Link, Shorten Urls, Your Own Website Link Where Users can Buy This Pack, etc )', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
       category = forms.ChoiceField(label='Category', choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

       class Meta:
           model = Product
           fields = ['title', 'details', 'image',
                  'sp', 'dp', 'buy_link', 'category']```
````

*My Views.py*

````
```def AddUserPacks(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
           userform = AddUserPacksForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
           if userform.is_valid():
               userpacks = userform.save(commit=False)
               userform.user = request.user.get_profile()
               userpacks.save()
               messages.success(request, f'Successfully Uploaded the post')
               return redirect('home')
           else:
               messages.info(request,"Something is wrong, Try Again")
       else:
           userform = AddUserPacksForm()
           return render(request, "gfx/post/post.html", {'form': userform})```
````

Comment: Did you try adding `user` to the fields list in form-Meta?

Comment: oo lol got it I forgot to add that 'user' in fields list in form-Meta also I did             userpacks.user = request.user in views.py and the code is now running well thx for help

Comment: Please describe the problem in your code. From what I read, I don't understand what is wrong (do you get an error?)